# how can i get a blob from mysql and show in a jtextpane?

Tags: java, mysql, blob

I am trying to show a image from mysql in a jtextpane but doesn't work,the problem appears when I try to turn the inputstream into BufferedImage, could you help me?

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 508, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    textPane.setEditable(false);
    textPane.setBounds(55, 40, 370, 192);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textPane);

    try{
        Statement a = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        ResultSet b = a.executeQuery("Select imagen from chat");
        InputStream i = null;
        ImageIcon ii = null;
        if (b.next()) {
            i = b.getBinaryStream("imagen");
            BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(i);
            ii = new ImageIcon(bi);
            textPane.insertIcon(ii);
        }
    } catch ( SQLException | IOException e) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 

}
```

the console said...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
at imagen.initialize(imagen.java:75)
```

I can't find the solution

Comment: I think you should carefully read the [Documentation of ImageIO.read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.InputStream)) to see if and when it returns `null`.

Comment: looks like the column valued you read from DB is null, make sure that the column name is correct.

Comment: @Jobin if that was true, the error would not be at the constructor of `ImageIcon` but rather before that.

Comment: try yo use the following code

    `Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob("ImageField");`
    `int blobLength = (int) blob.length();  `
    `byte[] imageAsBytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);    `
    `ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(imageAsBytes);`

Answer (score 0):

If the element on line 75 of the imagen.java file is probably null, you get a NullPointerException error. [Go to solutuon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218510/8171460)